# How do you remap a topic?

Tags: roslaunch, rosbag, topic, best-practices, remap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How to remap a topic name?

1. From a launch file?
2. From a bag file?

For example, I have a .bag file that publishes to a topic "foo" and I would like remap it to "bar", because another node expects the topic "bar".

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9248/how-do-you-remap-a-topic?/) by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 867 on 2011-03-01

Post score: 14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. The [remap](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML/remap) tag lets you remap topics in launch files.
2. rosbag play is a node just like any other and its published topics can be remapped in the same way as any other node. For example, if I have a bag file publishing a laser scan on /base_scan, but I want it on /scan, I can do `rosbag play my_bag.bag /base_scan:=/scan`

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2011-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 38

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [warriorUSP](https://answers.ros.org/users/36100/warriorusp/) on 2018-07-06**:
I think it is also necessary for the previous and the new topic to publish message of the same type for remap to work.

**Comment by [parzival](https://answers.ros.org/users/35453/parzival/) on 2019-06-06**:
Is it possible to do it on command line?

**Comment by [rfeistenauer](https://answers.ros.org/users/49423/rfeistenauer/) on 2019-11-15**:
`rosbag play my_bag.bag /base_scan:=/scan` should work

**Comment by [sgarciav](https://answers.ros.org/users/72940/sgarciav/) on 2022-06-15**:
In case someone runs into the issue while running ROS2, just add the `--remap` flag before remapping.
[Credit](https://answers.ros.org/question/345960/rosbag2-remap-topic/).

`$ ros2 bag play my_bag2.db3 --remap /base_scan:=/scan`